# ¿Cómo puedo insertar texto dentro de una caja flexible?

Tags: css, flexbox

Quiero introducir alguna especie de texto dentro de un contenedor con cajas flexibles pero al colocar un div interno no lo ejecuta dentro de el contenedor, a que se debe esto? Cómo puedo generar un espacio en el interior de el contenedor?

```
<div >
       <ul className='grid'>
           <li className='flex-item'>1
           <div>Un dispositivo.</div></li>
           <li className='flex-item'>1</li>
           <li className='flex-item'>1</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

y los estilos.css

```
.grid{   padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;

      justify-content: space-around;  } // justify-content: space-around;

.flex-item {    border-top-color: coral;
    border-width:1px; 
    border-style:solid;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;}
```

[image: introducir el código aquí]

Comment: Mi observaciones sobre tu código son las siguientes: 1. ¿Por que en el `HTML` usas `className` en lugar de `class`? Esto no debería funcionar. 2. Al asignar un `line-height: 150px;` lo que estas haciendo es "forzar" la alineación vertical, para la primer línea, es decir que la siguiente línea (`eg: <div>Un dispositivo.</div>`) va a estar `150px` mas abajo y es por esto que se desfaza (aparece por fuera de la "caja"). Si a `.flex-item` le agregas `overflow: auto`, vas a ver lo que te digo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al asignar un `line-height: 150px;` lo que estas haciendo es "forzar" la alineación vertical para la primer línea, es decir, la siguiente línea (`eg: <div>Un dispositivo.</div>`) va a estar `150px` mas abajo y es por esto que se desfasa (*aparece por fuera de la "caja"*)

### Solución:

Para centrar verticalmente el contenido dentro de cada `.flex-item`, podrías crear un `div` el cual se [`centre horizontal y verticalmente`](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

### Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.grid {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  border-top-color: coral;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

/* Centramos horizontal y verticalmente respecto del padre */
.flex-cont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class='grid'>
    <li class='flex-item'>
      <div class="flex-cont">
        1<br> Un dispositivo.
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='flex-item'>
      <div class="flex-cont">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class='flex-item'>
      <div class="flex-cont">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```